# Why didnt my system language change?

Tags: language-support

This is not a duplicate, so don't mark it as one.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 and the default language was English, and I wanted to switch it to Icelandic. So I did, and not only did the language not switch to Icelandic, but now my time and date will not display. What happened, and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you switch it to Icelandic?

Comment: I went to the Language Support on the system settings window

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you actually applied Icelandic. Did you just install it?

Comment: Did you click "apply system wide"? *Can* you click it? ( i.e. not grayed out)

Comment: The language never changed, I've restarted the system twice, still nothing

Comment: Can you please run the `locale` command in a terminal window, and copy and paste the answer here. Do so by editing your question rather than pasting it as a comment. Btw, if you haven't already done so, I'd like you to reinstall English too.

Comment: The language has changed, and the problem is resolved (powered off the system, and the changes finally took effect)... I will not reinstall English though

Answer (score 2):

Noticed what you wrote in comments. Installing Icelandic is not sufficient. You also need to drag the "Íslenska" item to the top of the list, to set the language related environment variables correctly.

"Drag languages to arrange them in order of preference."

(Uninstalling English was problably not a very good idea.)

Comment: "Íslenska" is at the top of the list (and it has been there since I installed it) but, nothing happened